# Can't compile C++ with Boost headers on a Macbook Air with M1 chip

Tags: c++, macos, boost, apple-m1

I am trying to run a C++ program with Boost headers. I am working on a Macbook Air with the M1 chip and had installed the latest version of Boost with `brew install boost`. For the M1 chip the default include folder is `/opt/homebrew/include`, which is a symlink to `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0`. For some reason when I compile with gcc (and g++) I keep getting the message `fatal error: 'boost/thread.hpp' file not found`.

My code and console commands are below:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void wait(int seconds)
{
  boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds{seconds});
}

void thread()
{
  using boost::this_thread::get_id;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    wait(1);
    std::cout << "Thread: " << i << std::endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  boost::thread t1{thread};
  t1.join();
}
```

The commands I am using are `gcc mythread.cpp -o mythread -l /opt/homebrew/include -l boost_thread-mt`.

The error message I get is:

```
mythread.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'boost/thread.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I can't figure out why the compiler is not seeing boost/thread.hpp.

Comment: Note `-l` and `-I` mean two very different things to the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

> For the M1 chip the default include folder is `/opt/homebrew/include`, which is a symlink to `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0`.

The above information is wrong. Use

```
-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include
```

Or, if there is such the reference

```
-I/opt/homebrew/include
```

Comment: Still can't get it to work: 
jane@MyLaptop c++ % gcc thread.cpp -o thread -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0
thread.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'boost/thread.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

Comment: Could you show the content of `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost` and `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0`?

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. Please use  `-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include`.

Answer (score 1):

```
g++ -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.82.0_1/lib -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.82.0_1/include/ -lboost_thread-mt --std=c++11 Main.cpp -o Main
```

- `-L` connects the static lib of thread lib in boost c++
- `-I` connects the header files of boost
- `-l` enables the thread management type